# Can Javascript objects call their own methods during construction?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS, interfacing with the [Undum](https://github.com/idmillington/undum) interactive fiction library:

```
undum.game.situations = {
main: new undum.SimpleSituation(
    "",
    {
        enter: function(character, system, from) {
            ...
        },
        actions: {
            testMethod: function() {
                return "hello from test method";
            },
            'test-action': function(character, system, action) {
                console.log("testMethod for main situation says: "+this.testMethod());
                ...
            }
        }
    }
),
...other situation defs
}
```

when I get into the test-action method of actions, the console shows the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.testMethod is not a function".

I'm guessing the problem is related to the fact that testMethod and its caller are defined as part of the SimpleSituation constructor?  If so, how should I go about setting up event-based code like this where an object needs to hook into its own methods during construction (although they aren't actually called during construction)?

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CresCoJeff/2k5u6je1/) with some similar boilerplate that I think demos the same categorical behavior is working fine:

```
function Obj(optionsObj) {
    optionsObj.testMethod();
}
var myObj = new Obj(
    {
        testMethod: function() {
            alert("hello from test method");
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Where is your `test-action` function being called?

Comment: The problem involves the way that the "test-method" function is being invoked. It doesn't have anything to do wit the declaration, I bet.

Comment: @Pointy yep, it was about the calling context which extracted the instance method and called it as a standalone function... for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding this problem was that in JS keyword this is all about the calling context rather than the called context -- I had read the [W3 schools blurb](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) about keyword this, but it's kind of misleading.  In their example code

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566,
  fullName : function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
};
```

they call out fullName as a method of person, in which keyword this will refer to the enclosing object.  That's only true, however, if the calling context of fullName is on an instance of person, e.g.

```
var p = new person();
p.fullName();
```

Being called on an instance of person is what makes fullName a method.  On its own, fullName is just a function like any other, however, and can be extracted from person and used as a standalone function:

```
var fullNameFn = person.fullName;
fullNameFn(); // in this case, keyword this points to global object (usually Window) or undefined in strict mode.
```

The situation I was looking at in Undum turned out to be such a case.  Instead of calling main.actions.test-action(), it was doing the following in response to player clicking an action link:

```
SimpleSituation.prototype.act = function(character, system, action) {
    // my take-action action function is extracted and stored as response
    var response = this.actions[action];
    try {
        response(character, system, action);
    } catch (err) {
        if (response) system.write(response);
    }
    if (this._act) this._act(character, system, action);
};
```

the actual test-action function is extracted from the Situation instance and executed standalone, causing keyword this to point to Window.